# Layout and importing for pytest in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, conda

I'm having trouble importing modules from my pytest functions. I know there's a million questions on this, but I've read through a bunch, and I'm still having trouble understanding.

```
$ tree
.
└── code
    ├── eight_puzzle.py
    ├── missionaries_and_cannibals.py
    ├── node.py
    ├── search.py
    └── test
        ├── test_eight_puzzle.py
        └── test_search.py

2 directories, 6 files
$
$ grep import code/test/test_search.py
import sys
import pytest
import code.search
$
$ pytest
...
ImportError while importing test module '~/Documents/code/test/test_search.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
code/test/test_search.py:14: in <module>
    import code.search
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.search'; 'code' is not a package
...
```

I expected that to work. 'code' is a package, right? A package in Python 3 is any directory with .py files in it.

I've also tried it with a relative import - `from .. import search` - and I get the following.

```
ImportError while importing test module '~/Documents/code/test/test_search.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
code/test/test_search.py:14: in <module>
    from .. import search
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've also tried modifying sys.path as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177081/4278309), specifying my PYTHONPATH, and adding **init**.py files in code and test.

Can I get this import to work without using something like setuptools? This is just for experimenting, so I'd rather not deal with the overhead.

It may also be important to note that I'm using conda, because it seems to work when I'm using the python 2 pip-installed version of pytest with **init**.py files.

Comment: Is the `code` directory missing an `__init__py` file to make it a package ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some notes about directories without `__init__.py` files first:

#### Implicit namespace packages

Although a directory without an `__init__.py` is a valid import source in Python 3, it is not a regular package, rather being an implicit namespace package (see [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for the details). Among other properties, implicit namespace packages are second-class citizens when it comes to importing, meaning that when Python has two packages with the same name in `sys.path`, one being a regular package and another being an implicit namespace package, the regular one will be preferred regardless what package comes first. Check it yourself:

```
$ mkdir -p implicit_namespace/mypkg
$ echo -e "def spam():\n    print('spam from implicit namespace package')" > implicit_namespace/mypkg/mymod.py
$ mkdir -p regular/mypkg
$ touch regular/mypkg/__init__.py
$ echo -e "def spam():\n    print('spam from regular package')" > regular/mypkg/mymod.py
$ PYTHONPATH=implicit_namespace:regular python3 -c "from mypkg.mymod import spam; spam()"
```

This will print `spam from regular package`: although `implicit_namespace` comes first in `sys.path`, `mypkg.mymod` from `regular` is imported instead because `regular/mypkg` is a regular package.

---

Now you know that since your package `code` is an implicit namespace package, Python will prefer regular imports of `code` to yours if it encounters one. Unfortunately for you, [there is a module `code` in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html), so it's practically a "reverse name shadowing" problem: you have an import object with the same name as the one from stdlib, but instead of shadowing the stdlib import, it shadows yours.

You thus need to do two things in order to make your layout usable:

1. give the `code` dir a unique name (let it be `mycode` for this answer's example)
2. after that, you still need to fix the `sys.path` when running the tests from the project root dir because it's not in `sys.path` per se. You have some possibilities:

   - add an empty `conftest.py` file to the root dir (aside the `mycode` dir). This will instruct `pytest` to add the root dir to `sys.path` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada/50610630#50610630) for an explanation). You can now just run `pytest` as usual and the imports will be resolved;
   - run the tests via `python -m pytest` - invoking interpreter directly adds the current dir to `sys.path`;
   - add the current dir to `sys.path` via `PYTHONPATH` env var, e.g. run `PYTHONPATH=. pytest`.