# Pytest - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x'

Tags: python, pytest

****solved: added `__init__.py` to `Test/` and renamed `testcode.py` to `test_code.py`. To run tests `cd -> Zee` and type `pytest`****

---

Structure:

```
|--Zee/
|   |--Test/
|   |   |--__init__.py
|   |   |--test_code.py
|   |--Codetotest/
|   |   |--code.py
```

in code.py

```
class Foo():
    some code...
```

in testcode.py

```
from Codetotest.code import Foo

def test_foo():
   assert ...
```

When I move to the `Zee` directory in my command line and run `pytest Test/testcode.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Zee`. How can I fix this?

I tried making Test a module by adding `Test/__init__.py` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816820/pytest-how-to-make-dedicated-test-directory). Ran from multiple directories, no dice.

Pytest version 5.3.4, imported from python 3.6

What I don't understand is, when I add `__init__.py` to `Zee/`, it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1):

You need a `__init__.py` in the module directory.

Here's a typical project structure:

```
|--zee-project-directory/
|   |--tests/
|   |   |--test_zee.py
|   |--zee/
|   |   |--__init__.py
|   |   |--code.py
```

code.py

```py
class Foo():
    some code...
```

test_zee.py

```py
from zee.code import Foo

def test_foo():
   assert ...
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I tried running pytest testcode.py from ```zee-project-directory```, ```tests``` and ```zee```.

Comment: Run from `zee-project-directory`, no need to specify `tests` as it is the default path. Make sure to change the import like in my example above: `from zee.code import Foo`. Please copy the new error message / stacktrace.

Comment: Working now. I put ```__init__.py``` in ```Test/``` and renamed my file to ```test_whatever``` as I should have done from the start #rtfm

Comment: I don't think you even need __init__.py in tests. The way pytest behaves, test tiles don't have to be modules (unless they import stuff from each other).

Comment: Anyway, glad you solved it and welcome to SO. You may
[upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow/173400#173400)
/
[accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)
this answer.

Comment: Upvoted. Your answer was helpful, but I had to put the ```__init__.py``` in the ```tests/```, not ```zee/``` folder

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do need `__init__.py` in `zee` and you don't need it in `tests`.

Comment: ¯¯¯\__(ツ)__/¯¯¯

Comment: I too had to add it to `tests`. Being in the module and other sub-module folders wasn't sufficient.