# Import file from parent directory when using PyTest?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using PyTest, but it can't seem to run my import statements.

My directory structures is like this:

```
-[app]
   -script1.py
-[tests]
   -test1.py
```

My `test1.py` file includes this line:

```
from script1 import my_func
```

and I get an error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named script1` when I run pytest from the command line.

I tried adding this statement to `cd` the directory above but it didn't work:

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26804421/5986907

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=app/ pytest tests/test1.py` should work, or (if using Python 3) add an empty `conftest.py` file in the project root (along the dirs `app` and `tests`) and change the import to `from app.script1 import my_func`; `app` is then treated as an implicit namespace package.

Answer (score -2):

Like you specified. script1.py module is in [app]
So it should be

```
from app.script1 import my_func
```

or if you want to import all functions from script.py

```
import app.script1
```

and just call any function

```
script1.anyfunction()
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - [app] is a folder, not a file

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder