# Python2 Relative Imports

Tags: python, python-2.x

In Python2, I have the following directory structure:

```
Project
|____Tests
     |____tester.py
|____Scripts
     |____run_test_1.py
     |____run_test_2.py
```

In `tester.py`, I have a class called `Tester`, which takes in some arguments, and then runs a test (details are not important). In `run_test_1.py` and `run_test_2.py`, I create a Tester object, with a certain set of arguments, and run this test.

But I am having difficulty with relative imports. In `run_test_1.py`, I have the line `from Tests import tester`. However, if I run `python run_test_1.py` from the command line, I receive the error `No module named Tests`. I think that this is because Python only searches the current directory for packages, so it cannot find my `Tests` directory.

So, what should I do instead? One solution is to move `run_test_1.py` up one level, so that it is in the `Project` directory. This works, because Python searches the current directory and it can then find `Tests`. But for my particular case, I want `run_test_1.py` to be in the `Scripts` directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Show an MCVE please. And a full stack trace. I suspect you can reproduce the error with just a couple of lines per snippet

Comment: Does this solve your problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26804421/75103

Comment: Obligatory reminder: Don't use python2 except for nostalgic reasons. It is not supported anymore