# Command line and REPL works but script got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named`?

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure. And I'm in `.`.

```
./ # current directory
  __init__.py
  module_1/
    __init__.py
    util
      __init__.py  # contains f1(), f2(), ...
    test.py
```

The following python command works fine

```
python -c "from module_1.util import f1, f2"
```

Running in REPL works fine too.

```
Python 3.8.11 (default, Aug  6 2021, 09:57:55) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from module_1.util import f1, f2
>>>
```

However, execute the test.py got the error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_1'`. test.py has only one line

```
from module_1.util import f1, f2
```

Run script:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\X\src> python .\module_1\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\module_1\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module1.util import f1, f2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_1'
```

Comment: have you tried `from ..module_1.util import f1, f2` ? (where the double `..` moves up one level in the dir)

Comment: It got the error of `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` if adding `..`.

Comment: You might need an empty `__init__.py` in your test dir

Comment: ohh and you need an `__init__.py` in you `module_1` dir

Comment: basically `__init__.py` tells python that things can be imported from that directory. You can do things like in `module_1/__init__.py` write `from .util import f1, f2` which would then let you import `f1` and `f2` directly from `module_1`

Comment: @Schalton, actually I have `__init__.py` in module_1. Why the command `python -c "from module_1.util import f1, f2"` works (tried in REPL too) but not in the script?

Comment: I think you need to create a proper package (using setup.py); I updated my answer below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python project directory structure / pytest trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804421/python-project-directory-structure-pytest-trouble)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the name of the dir ".", which I will call DOT dir, and do something like:

```
from DOT.module_1.util import f1, f2
```

you may need to add the DOT dir or the parent of the DOT dir to your PYTHONPATH variable.

Also add the `__init__.py` in test

and the f1() f2() should be in the util.py file

Comment: Yep, lots of people put all of their code in a "`src`" directory

Comment: yep, generally should be src for convention, but I don't know how the "." dir was called in this case. Didn't want to create confusion.

Comment: @lsy89, wasn't criticizing the response, just giving the tidbit to OP in case they decided to take this approach.

-- For simple projects this is likely what I would do, the only downside is if they become more complex you can end up with circular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

```
./
  setup.py
  __init__.py
  module_1/
    __init__.py
    util
      __init__.py  # contains f1(), f2(), ...
  test/
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

in test.py:

```
from module_1.util import f1,f2
```

in `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='module_1', packages=['module_1'])
```

"install" [link] with `python setup.py develop`

---

Optionally you could add the import to the `module_1/__init__.py` as follows:

```
# module_1/__init__.py
from .util import f1, f2
```

which would allow you to import it directly in `test.py`

```
# test.py
from ..moduel_1 import f1, f2
```